# How to insert data in to columns separately in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert

I try to insert data into columns separately in postgreSQL. 
First i insert column1 and then column2.
But this is what happens;

```
column1   column2
   1
   2
   3
           1a
           2b
           3c
```

column 2 starts where column1 ends..
I want to insert it like;

```
column1   column2
   1        1a
   2        2b
   3        3c
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Where is your data? What is your current query? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: what do you expect? `insert` creates a new record. it doesn't go back and modify previous records. that's what `update` is for. if you want a single record, then `insert+update`, or `insert col1,col2` at the same time

Comment: I already have data in my first column and the data type is serial. I try to insert data into second column from csv file by using python. But it starts inserting data from the row number where column 1 ends. For example ; If the last row number is 25 in column 1, it starts inserting the data from row number 26 in the second column. It doesn't start row number 1 , which what i want to.

Comment: Databases work on `records` (rows) where each column is a `field`.  You can't "insert columns" like in Excel, you need to modify the fields of existing records.

Answer (score 0):

Im totally guessing, but you probably need something like

Use `JOIN` to build a single result

```
 INSERT INTO newTable
      SELECT First.column1, Second.column2
      FROM First
      JOIN Second
        ON First.ID = Second.ID
```

Comment: I already have data in my first column and the data type is serial. I try to insert data into second column from csv file by using python. But it starts inserting data from the row number where column 1 ends. For example ; If the last row number is 25 in column 1, it starts inserting the data from row number 26 in the second column. It doesn't start row number 1 , which what i want to.

Comment: Read the links I provide. You need include more information in your question. Because right now there isnt way to answer it.